# Materialize CSS: how to set footer height?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I would like to reduce the size (height) of the footer whilst keeping it sticky at the bottom of the page.

HTML:

```
<footer class="page-footer grey lighten-2">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="row">
            <p id="updatedText" style="color:black"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  main { flex: 1 0 auto; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to set height of elements in CSS?  If so, try...

```
   footer {
    height: 200px;
    }
```

I'd avoid having a footer class within the footer element, as it could get confusing.  Try and rename it to something more meaningful.

Comment: The above does not work, this is very obvious but it does not work with this library.

Comment: So what else have you tried?  Did you get it to work?